# Unable to start tomcat

Tags: 18.04, tomcat8

I tried to install Tomcat-8 on my Ubuntu 18 and did all the basic configuration including JAVA setup, environment variable, files/folders permission and creation of service file.
But the moment I try to run Tomcat it gives me error and terminates. From logs or "journalctl -xe" brief details are as follows:

```
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver startup.sh[3626]: Existing PID file found during start.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver startup.sh[3626]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver startup.sh[3626]: Tomcat started.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver shutdown.sh[3647]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission t
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: **tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1**
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: **tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.**
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: **Failed to start Tomcat 8 servlet container.**
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit tomcat.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: Stopped Tomcat 8 servlet container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: **tomcat.service: Start request repeated too quickly.**
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: **tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.**
Jul 04 00:59:01 myserver systemd[1]: **Failed to start Tomcat 8 servlet container.**
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Can someone guide what I did wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the user being used to start the Tomcat server does not have permissions to remove/modify the PID file (which contains the process ID of a running instance of the server).  You may have initially started Tomcat as root, Tomcat improperly shut down for another reason (leaving behind the old PID file owned by root), but then switched to another user (who cannot remove/modify the root owned file).  You may need to become root and correct the PID file's ownership to that of the user who will run Tomcat, or simply remove the old PID file as root.

Comment: I performed the installation with ROOT user and created all environment variables with ROOT user too. Even the folder access for tomcat.pid is set as 755. Still I face the same error. Please suggest some more checks where I can look around for possible error.

Comment: 755 is going to give the owning user full access and the group owner and world read and execute (but not write access).  Under default conditions, Tomcat is run as the tomcat user.  So the tomcat user may not be able to write nor modify the pid file, given the additional details you've provided and depending on the owning user and group owner of the pid file and it's parent directory as well as the run user and group of Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for reverting, but as I mentioned, installation is done under ROOT user. Additionally I'm running Tomcat service with ROOT user only. All files/folders permission was set good for ROOT user. I did stop/start along with clearing all buffers/cache. Performed system reboot too. Still facing the same error. Even removed the old PID file. Nothing worked. Can you guide more?